# Why can "conda" and "conda-env" packages not be cloned?

Tags: python, anaconda, virtualenv, conda

I have the anaconda virtual environment. I need to add packages to the environment and rename it. I googled it and understood that i need to clone, then add packages.

I had tried to clone the environment, but **conda** and **conda-env** packages cannot be cloned. How can i fix it?

```
conda create --prefix /path/to/newenv --clone /path/to/oldenv
Source:      /path/to/oldenv
Destination: /path/to/newenv
The following packages cannot be cloned out of the root environment:
 - conda-4.3.30-py35hf9359ed_0
 - conda-env-2.6.0-h36134e3_1
Packages: 296
Files: 45667
bzip2-1.0.6-3. 100% |#########################################################################################################################| Time: 0:00:00   1.05 MB/s
```

Then, i can not install packages with conda in new environment.

Answer (score 1):

To create a new conda environment with the packages you want to use, just use `conda create`. For example:

```
conda create -n myenv package1 package2 package3
```

creates a new environment named `myenv` and containing the packages `package1`, `package2` and `package3`. conda will figure out and install the dependencies of those packages as well. If you want to install more packages in this environment later on, just `activate` it then use `conda install`.

If you want to develop in this environment using an editor that's provided by a conda package, for example Spyder or Jupyter, then don't forget to install those packages in the environment too.

You might want to use `conda clone` to make a copy of an existing environment that you have created before making specific changes to it, but it doesn't make sense to try and clone `root`.